# C# Indexing - Can i return the whole Class?

Tags: c#, class, indexing

appologies if I am missing osmething obvious with this one!

Im hoping to have the User decalare a code and then refence the Class name and pull all Data from it.

here is where I will be displaying said info back to the user:

```
   Console.Write("Input a code:");
                Console.Read();


                Console.WriteLine("code: " + HU2H02.HeadCode);
                    var i = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("Stop No:     Station:      Arr:     Dep:");
                    foreach (Station stop in HU2H02.CallingPattern)
                    {
                    if (i < HU2H02.CallingPattern.Count-1)
                    {   
                        if (i == 0)
                            Console.WriteLine("stop {0}: {1} \t  {3: hh:mm}", i, stop.Name, HU2H02.ArrTimes[i], HU2H02.DepTimes[i]);
                        else
                        Console.WriteLine("stop {0}: {1} \t {2: hh:mm} - {3: hh:mm}", i, stop.Name, HU2H02.ArrTimes[i], HU2H02.DepTimes[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("stop {0}: {1} \t {2: hh:mm}", i, stop.Name, HU2H02.ArrTimes[i]);
                    }
                        i++;
                    }
```

Here is my Class code: (Sorry its a bit messy as im still working on it.

```
     class Train
    {
        public string HeadCode { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public List<Station> callingPattern = new List<Station>();
        public List<DateTime> arrTimes = new List<DateTime>();
        public List<DateTime> depTimes = new List<DateTime>();
        public DateTime DepartOrigin { get; set; }
        public DateTime ArriveDestination { get; set; }
        public string Via1 { get; set; }
        public string Via2 { get; set; }
        public string Via3 { get; set; }
        public string Via4 { get; set; }

        public object this[string Headcode]
        {
            get
            {

                Type myType = typeof(Train);
                PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(Headcode);
                return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
            }
            set
            {
                Type myType = typeof(Train);
                PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(Headcode);
                myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);

            }
        }

        public Train(List<Station> patterns, string newheadCode, string timetoDepartOrigin, string Origin)
        {
            TimeSpan previousTime = new TimeSpan();
            TimeSpan holder = new TimeSpan();
            TimeSpan calcTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Station pattern in patterns)
            {
                CallingPattern.Add(pattern);

                if (pattern.Name == Origin)
                {

                    depTimes.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(timetoDepartOrigin));
                    ArrTimes.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(timetoDepartOrigin));
                    previousTime = TimeSpan.Parse(timetoDepartOrigin);
                }
                else
                {
                    holder = TimeSpan.Parse(callingPattern[callingPattern.Count - 2].DwellTimePeak);
                    calcTimeSpan = previousTime + holder;
                    ArrTimes.Add(DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(calcTimeSpan)));

                    if (callingPattern[callingPattern.Count - 1].DwellTimePeak != null)
                    {
                        holder = TimeSpan.Parse(callingPattern[callingPattern.Count - 1].DwellTimePeak);
                        calcTimeSpan = calcTimeSpan + holder;
                        depTimes.Add(DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(calcTimeSpan)));

                        previousTime = depTimes[depTimes.Count - 1].TimeOfDay + TimeSpan.Parse(callingPattern[callingPattern.Count - 1].TimetonextStationUP[patterns[i + 1].Name]);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }


            HeadCode = newheadCode;
            DepartOrigin = Convert.ToDateTime(timetoDepartOrigin);
        }

        public List<DateTime> ArrTimes { get => arrTimes; set => arrTimes = value; }
        public List<DateTime> DepTimes { get => depTimes; set => depTimes = value; }
        internal List<Station> CallingPattern { get => callingPattern; set => callingPattern = value; }



        }
    }
}
```

Do i need to declare the whole class as Public also?

Im hoping to parse the whole Class back to the Main program or another class for Display and further use as I want this class to be a sub class of a few other classes later on in the design of my program..

im a bit fresh at C# so appologies if any of this does not make sense! Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What is your indexed property (`public object this[string Headcode]`) supposed to do?  Are you trying to have a collection of `Train` objects and pull out one of them?  If so, then you will likely make that collection `static` and have static accessors (properties or methods) to maintain and access the collection

Comment: FlyDog, Yes I am trying to make a collection of Train objects and pull one that the user defines by its code. The (public object this[string Headcode]) Was from an example I found around indexing, However I had not suited it to my exact needs/Got it working!

Comment: IN an Ideal world, I would like to be bale to have something like ("HU"+ Readline("2H20").Headcode) or ("HU"+ Readline("2H20").Calling Pattern), Is that Even possible?

Comment: If you post another question, it would be a good idea to read something like [mcve] and boil the code that post down to something that doesn't have as much detail.  Most of the detail in the code you posted has nothing to do with what you are asking about (well, I don't think it does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look up a train, you need to maintain a `static` collection of trains.  Static variables and functions operate at the class level (rather than the instance level).

Add something like this to your class:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Train> _trains;
private Train GetTrain(string headCode) {
    if (_trains.TryGetValue(headCode, out var train)) {
        return train;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
private bool TryGetTrain(string headCode, out Train train) {
    return _trains.TryGetValue(headCode, out train);
}
```

And, then at the end of your constructor, add some code like this:

```
 _trains.Add(newHeadCode, this);
```

Every time you create a new train, it will be added to that dictionary of trains. Then, when you want to look up a train, you can do this.

```
var myTrain = Train.GetTrain("some head code");
```

Comment: Perfect, and well explained, hanks Flydog! All seems so simple now :D

Answer (score 0):

if you don't define class as anything, it'll remains as private. 
private class cannot be access on other class. 
so we define it as internal or public.

internal class can be access on any class which contains current project.
public class is accessable on any class even it's other project.

choose it depends on your purpose.

Comment: Aaah thankyou! I was unaware of the default Private status of class!

Comment: internal is the default access modifier for classes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-and-struct-accessibility